# How to define (natural) conjugate prior for this linear model?

Tags: self-study, bayesian, conjugate-prior

I have the  general linear regression model, $\ y = Xβ+e $ , where $\ e ∼ N$ $\ (0, σ^2 * I_T),

$\ X $ is a (T × K) fixed non-stochastic matrix of regressors, $\ y $ is a (T × 1) vector of observations and $\beta $ is a (K ×1) vector of parameters.

My questions:

How can I define a conjugate prior and of a natural conjugate prior with regards to this model?

The prior p.d.f. for $\beta $ conditional on $\sigma^2$ is a multivariate normal distribution, ($\beta $|$\sigma^2$) ∼ N ($\beta $,$\sigma^2A^-1$)

How can I find the kernel of this distribution, absorbing any constant terms into the proportionality constant?

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice.

Comment: For the other I was asking about c) and d) not a)